# Logging Multidimensional Arrays with Template Literals

Tags: javascript, console.log, template-literals

How can I `console.log()` a multidimensional array using Template Literals without having it convert the array into a string?

Here is an example showing the difference between using and not using Template Literals to log the array:

```
const multidimensionalArray = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]];

console.log(multidimensionalArray ); 
    // [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4, 5 ], [ 6, 7, 8, 9 ] ]

console.log(`My nested Array: ${multidimensionalArray}`);
    //My nested Array: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: No. Template strings are what their name suggests - strings. For alternative suggestions, there is currently at least one answer with a pretty nice one already.

Comment: Other options than the answer are: `console.log("my nested Array",multidimensionalArray);` If you mutate `multidimensionalArray` after the console.log and you expand the result in the console you'll see the array as it is now and not at the time of logging, you can do the following: `console.log("My nested Array:",JSON.stringify(multidimensionalArray))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `JSON.stringify` inside placeholder, otherwise your array is converted to string with `toString` method.

```js
const multidimensionalArray = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]];
console.log(`My nested Array: ${JSON.stringify(multidimensionalArray)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make use of a lesser known feature! `console.table()`

*Note you need to open the actual console for this, SO doesn't support it yet.

```js
const multidimensionalArray = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]];
console.table(multidimensionalArray)
```